# Pointer and reference variable syntax order in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, reference

I've been studying C++ and I started to wonder when you declare pointers or references (and constants):

```
int *a; 
int* a; 
char &b; 
char& b; 
const char c; 
char const c;
```

Are the both declarations for `a, b` and `c` equivalent? Are they allowed?

Thnx for any help! :)

Comment: yes (filler goes here)

Comment: +1 @LuchianGrigore thnx :)

Comment: Do you mean "const char c VS char const c" OR "const char* c VS char* const c"?

Comment: whitespaces in C generally don't make much difference

Comment: only becarefull in condtions like these `int *i, j;` Here `i` is a pointer to in and j is an int. Would you like both to be pointers use `int *i, *j;`

Comment: +1 @Yousf I didn't mean neither of the examples you gave, but I'm eager to hear difference if you want to explain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're identical.

The general rule is that if a `const` is next to a type name then the type is constant. If it's next to a pointer then it's the pointer that's constant. If it's next to both then it binds to the type. So:

```
char const a; // constant character
char const *b; // non constant pointer to constant data
char * const c; // constant pointer to non constant data
char const * const d; constant pointer to constant data
```

References are constant by default in that they cannot be changed to reference anything else once they're initialized. Using the rules above means that when `const` is appliced to a reference it means that the type/data is constant.

Comment: There is a nice general rule, how to read the definitions: Start from the identifier name, read all symbols to the right from the identifier (the closest symbol goes first), then read symbols to the left. E.g. "char const * c[]" means "c is an array of pointers to const char"

Comment: That's _not_ the general rule for `const` (and doesn't cover all of the cases, either).  The general rule for `const` is that it modifies what is to the left of it, and only if nothing is to the left does it modify what is to the right.

Comment: Correct, thus "const char * p" and "char const * p" declares the same. One might read the first declaration as "p is a pointer to a char which is const". And the second "p is a pointer to constant char".

Answer (score 2):

"YES" is the answer to both your questions. :D
You got it right dude!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hey are identical, although a reference and a pointer, and const thereof are not the same things.

Just as a style issue, I try to keep the "&" and "*" with the variable.  Many programmers have the habit (good or bad is debate topic for other post) of declaring multiple variables with the same type on the same line.

For example:

```
// Creates three pointers to FruitClass instances.
FruitClass *apple, *lemon, *grapes;
```

If you get into the habit of putting the "&" or "*" with the type, you may be tempted to type:

```
// Creates a pointer to a FruitClass instance and two FruitClass instances.
// This is probably **not** what you wanted to do.
// And if it is, put these on separate lines because everybody will ask 
// if you intended to do this and waste your/their time.
FruitClass* apple, lemon, grapes;
```

These are **very** different things.

This is a minor point, and the universe will not self-destruct if you do it the second way instead of the first.  Just beware when the compiler starts barking (which it will when you try to use it as a reference/pointer and it is not).

It is also part of coding standards I have worked with.  If you are using a standard, be sure to follow it, avoiding wasting time and frustration during a code inspection (because if you have a standard, **somebody** will be inspecting the code, formally or informally).

Comment: +1 @Nonlinearldeas thank you for your help :) Could you explain the difference between the examples you gave? :)

Comment: I added some comments to the code.  Was this what you were looking for?